# Calculate sum of attribute field using Leaflet and Esri Leaflet plugin

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I am adding Esri feature layer to Leaflet map from Esri REST API.
I can access the feature properties, like this

```js
feature.properties.CasesField
```

How can I iterate through this CasesField and get:

1. All the values
2. Sum the values

```js
function initMap() {
  map = L.map("map", {
    zoomControl: true,

    zoomSnap: 0.25
  }).setView([33.1625662, -96.6390040], 5); //home position
  ;

  L.esri.basemapLayer("Topographic").addTo(map);

  casese = L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: casesURL,
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      var props = feature.properties.CasesField;


      var sum = 0;
      for (x in props) {
        sum += props;
      }

      // use the value to do something...

      console.log(sum);

    }

  }).addTo(map);

}
```

Comment: What is the content of this `feature.properties.CasesField` property?

Comment: @TomzicM its a number field, also would like access other string field as well.

Comment: If it's single number field, why are you summing it in a loop? Or does it mean you want sum this one field across all the features?

Comment: Yes, would like to sum this one field across all the features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `sum` variable outside feature processing function as global variable. Then you have to wait for feature layer `load` event before you can use/display sum.

Code could then look something like this:

```
var sum = 0;

var casese = L.esri.featureLayer({
  url: casesURL,
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    sum += feature.properties.CasesField;
  }
}).addTo(map);

casese.on('load', function() {
  console.log(sum);
});
```

Comment: Thank you,  Yes that it, it worked perfectly.